# What to do when my Wubi install boots to a command line environment?

Tags: boot, wubi

I installed Ubuntu with wubi.exe and I rebooted my computer. When booting, I chose Ubuntu and entered my username and password. Then I got to the terminal. What commands should I type in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get to your desktop environment. Type:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will be prompted to enter your user password. This should bring up your normal login screen that you use to login to your desktop environment.

In Ubuntu 15.04 and later, run this command instead:

```
systemctl start lightdm.service
```

If this works you should ask yourself why your computer didn't boot straight into your normal login screen. Possibly because you haven't installed the recommended driver for your graphics processor from *System Settings* -> *Additional Drivers* for Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 or *Dash* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers* tab for Ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 13.10.